# Create multidimensional array in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

I have array with 45 elements. I need to make from it multidimensiona array.
This is how it looks like:

```
Array45: [
         0 => {
              +'MODEL': "AAA"
              +'PRICE': 12.00
              +'SUBMODEL_NAME': "abc"
              }
         1 => {
              +'MODEL': "AAA"
              +'PRICE': 12.00
              +'SUBMODEL_NAME': ""
              }
         2 => {
              +'MODEL': "BBB"
              +'PRICE': 12.00
              +'SUBMODEL_NAME': "bcd"
              }
         3 => {
              +'MODEL': "AAA"
              +'PRICE': 12.00
              +'SUBMODEL_NAME': ""
              }
]
```

And now: If record doesn't have 'SUBMODEL_NAME' I need to put it in one array with previous record which has 'SUBMODEL_NAME'. And in this case it should look like:

```
Array: [
         0 => [ 
              0 => {
                    +'MODEL': "AAA"
                    +'PRICE': 12.00
                    +'SUBMODEL_NAME': "abc"
                   }
              1 => {
                    +'MODEL': "AAA"
                    +'PRICE': 12.00
                    +'SUBMODEL_NAME': ""
                   }

         1 => [ 
              0 => {
                    +'MODEL': "BBB"
                    +'PRICE': 12.00
                    +'SUBMODEL_NAME': "bcd"
                   }
              1 => {
                    +'MODEL': "AAA"
                    +'PRICE': 12.00
                    +'SUBMODEL_NAME': ""
                   }
]
```

etc.

I'm in foreach loop where I try to put every next record without SUBMODEL_NAME to previous but I get stuck. 
It's something like this:

```
$j = -1;
$newArray = [];

foreach($items as $item){

        if ($index->SUBMODEL_NAME) {
            $j++;
            $newArray [$j][] = $index ;
        }
  }
```

**EDIT**
Thank you all for help! I've implement soulution proposed by @user1309690 and it looks like it works perfectly. Thank for you'r help and time

Comment: You might want to correct the spelling in your title Jakmen.

Comment: @jakmen Grouping doesn't make much sense to me here. You need those elements which have SUBMODEL_NAME to come before the ones which don't have. Okay. But, why are they inside an individual subgroup of size 2? Also, how did one qualify for any individual subgroup in the output?

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
$j = -1;
$newArray = [];
foreach($items as $item){
    if ($item['SUBMODEL_NAME']) {
        $j++;
    }
    $newArray [$j][] = $item ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it-

```
$result = [];
foreach($array as $k=>$v){
    $i=0;
    if($v['SUBMODEL_NAME']==''){
        $i++;
        $k = $k-1;
    }
    $result[$k][$i]= $v;
}
$result = array_values($result);
print_r($result);
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/3aTgR